Discrepancy in Effect Size Sign when Using "escalc" vs "rma" Functions in metafor package in R
I'm working on a meta-analysis and encountered an issue that I’m hoping someone can help clarify. When I calculate the effect size using the escal function, I get a negative effect size (Hedge's g) for one of the studies (let's call it Study A). However, when I use the rma function from the metafor package, the same effect size turns positive. Interestingly, all other effect sizes still follow the same direction.
Has anyone else encountered this discrepancy between the two functions, or could you explain why this might be happening?
I have attached the forest plot. The study in question is Camarena et al, 2014. The correct effect size for it should be: -0.50 [-0.86, -0.15]
I used the Rstudio interface for the analysis
Here is the code that I used:
datPr <- escalc(measure="SMD", m1i=Smean, sd1i=SSD, n1i=SizeS, m2i=Cmean, sd2i=CSD, n2i=SizeC, data=Suicide_Persistence)
datPr


resPr <- rma(measure="SMD", yi, vi, data=Suicide_Persistence)
resPr

forest(resPR,  xlab = "Hedge's g", header = "Author(s), Year", slab = paste(Studies, sep = ", "), shade = TRUE, cex = 1.0, xlab.cex = 1.1, header.cex = 1.1, psize = 1.2)

I've checked the data, and it's clear that the effect size for Study A should be negative (i.e., experimental group mean score is smaller than control group). To further confirm, I recalculated the effect size for Study A using Review Manager (RevMan), and the result is still negative.

You are not using data=datPr in your call to rma(), but data=Suicide_Persistence. So the mistake lies in variable yi in dataset Suicide_Persistence.
